# Dependency injection with IOC containers: Give service depending on who is asking for it

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

Let's say I have third-party libraries `L1` and `L2` that both require an `IFoo` service (something general; could be an `ILogger`, for instance).

I want to control which implementation the different libraries get.

I can't use keyed or named services, as `L1` and `L2` themselves wouldn't know about it.

So really I would want to register a factory for `IFoo` that gets the information *for whom* it's supposed to resolve the service.

What's the approach that is usually taken here?

I'm asking both for IOC containers and frameworks in general as well as specifically for the one used by ASP.NET Core, which is the platform I deal with most.

Comment: It depends a lot on the DI Container at hand. MS.DI, for instance, has little support for this; you'll basically be forced to to fallback from Auto-Wiring to a lambda registration. More mature DI Containers often have more options but, again, it depends on which DI Container you are using.

Comment: There are many DI Containers, such as Autofac, Simple Injector, Ninject, Castle Windsor, Lamar, LightInject. I am only really experienced with one of them, which is Simple Injector, but your milleage might vary. [Here's the documentation section](https://simpleinjector.org/advanced#context-based-injection) about context-based injection, which is what you are looking for.